# pub : The term 'pub' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,

Tags: flutter, dart, aqueduct

I want to install aqueduct on my pc.
I run this command

```
pub global activate aqueduct
```

but I get this error

```
pub : The term 'pub' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pub global activate aqueduct
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pub:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I tried to run it with `dart pub global activate aqueduct`

it worked but when I want to create a new project, I get this error.

the code of create new project, `aqueduct create my_app`
the error

```
aqueduct : The term 'aqueduct' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ aqueduct create my_app
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (aqueduct:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I tried with dart also: `dart aqueduct create my_app`

I get this error:

```
Could not find a command named "aqueduct".

Usage: dart <command|dart-file> [arguments]
```

Comment: You might need to add the pub cache directory to your PATH. https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd/pub-global#running-a-script-from-your-path

Comment: it is already added. still get this error, but I can't find the file of pub, is not exist

Comment: aqueduct was discontinued over 2 years ago. You'll likely want to start from shelf and build your own functionality.